# React Native : [Expo] Library which capture the main color from an image taken by Camera roll?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to take a picture of something and then want to extract the main color from that image.
It will be like when you have a certain item and you want to add its color, But to be exact you want to take a picture of that item and then extract the exact color from that picture and set it against the item.

I have tried looking for it what I found was:

`color-thief` which failed on react native
`react-native-image-color-picker` which somehow didn't work either.

I did tried couple of other options from online resources but I couldn't get the desired results.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to fix this issue